# excel vba 2147221080 - Automation error reopening Backend/Data workbook

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I´ve been getting an automation error and so far have been unsuccessful to prevent it.
Since it seems like the cause for this can be very different from case to case, i´ll try my best to describe my project:

Inside of a frontend workbook there is all the code and inside a backend workbook there is the relevant data. 
On startup the frontend opens the backend like this

```
    Set daten_betrieb = Workbooks.Open(speicherort & "GB-Backend-" & kuerzel_betrieb & ".xlsx", _
                                UpdateLinks:=0, _
                                ReadOnly:=True, _
                                IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, _
                                Notify:=False, _
                                CorruptLoad:=xlNormalLoad)
```

Everything works fine except when the user manually reopens the backend and closes it, while the frontend is still open. 
I added the following line to the code
`If daten_betrieb Is Nothing Then Call backend_betrieb`
backend_betrieb is the sub that uses the Workbooks.Open method mentioned earlier.

Even though the backend is open (again), i still get **2147221080 - Automation error** on this line:

```
If daten_betrieb.Sheets("Arbeitsmittel & AKZ").Cells(1, i).Value = Arbeitsmittel Then
```

daten_betrieb refers to the freshly opened Workbook which is set to this name.. why is this a problem? Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance!

**Edit:**
Maybe the problem is with `If backend_betrieb Is Nothing Then call backend_betrieb`
When stepping through I see that excel doesnt jump into the sub backend_betrieb(). Does excel somehow think that the name/variable "backend_betrieb" is still there --> not Nothing. But the Workbook behind it is closed which leads to the error?!

Comment: Calling `Workbooks.Open` on an already open file can cause issues.

Comment: Hi BigBen, thanks for the reply. The Workbook is not already open in that case. The backend is closed beforehand.

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to handle the Error.

```
On Error Resume Next
If daten_betrieb.Sheets("Arbeitsmittel & AKZ").Cells(1, i).Value = Arbeitsmittel Then
  xxx        
End If
If Err.Number = -2147221080 Then    
  Set daten_betrieb = Nothing
  GoTo Start
End If
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
```

Start is at the beginning of the sub, before `If daten_betrieb Is Nothing call backend_betrieb`

So basically it really seems like the Workbook was closed (manually through the user) but the object/name/whatever "daten_betrieb" was not Nothing. So i had to set it to Nothing for the `If daten_betrieb Is Nothing call backend_betrieb` line to take action.